TYPO3 EXT:femanager extended with a select field
I followed the example on how to extended femanager with my own fields ...
(https://docs.typo3.org/p/in2code/femanager/7.3/en-us/Features/NewFields/Index.html)
I need to add a select field that lists a number of user types ...
I've got it working up to this error:
The argument "options" was registered with type "array", but is of type "string" in view helper "In2code\Femanager\ViewHelpers\Form\SelectViewHelper". 
my new field partial calls the form field like this:
<femanager:form.select
  id="femanager_field_usertype"
  property="userType"
  options="{1:private, 2:business, 3:real estate agent}"
  defaultOption="{f:translate(key:'pleaseChoose')}"
  class="form-control"
  additionalAttributes="{femanager:Validation.FormValidationData(settings:settings,fieldName:'userType')}" />

I work with:

TYPO3 V11.5.37
femanager 7.3.1


The problem seems to be the options attribute:
Change it from:
options="{1:private, 2:business, 3:real estate agent}"

to:
options="{1: 'private', 2: 'business', 3: 'real estate agent'}"


spot on, I didn't think of that and I tried quite a few !!! if I'd like to use .xlf instead of 'private' etc. ?

Should work like {1: 'EXT:my_ext/Resoureces/Private/Language/loccallang.xlf:my-key', 2: .....}. Give it a try.

thanks, the hint gave me a working solution:
{1: '{f:translate(key: 'LLL:EXT:my_ext/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:my-key')}', 2: ...

Oh yes. I forgot the LLL ;-)   Sorry
